# Probability of two passengers will be staying at same inn

Tags: probability

**There are three passengers on an airport shuttle bus that makes stops at five different inns. Find the probability that two passengers will be staying at same inn**

I think there are two events: Just 2 passengers at same inn or just 3 passengers at same inn. So
$ \binom{3}{2} $ is the number of ways in which you can choose the 2 passengers out of 3 passengers that are in same inn, $ \binom{5}{1} $ is the number of ways in which you can choose 1 inn out of 5 inns that the 2 or 3 passengers are , $ \binom{3}{3} $  is the number of ways in which you can choose 3 passagers out of 3 passengers that are in same inn

Result:
$ \frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{5}{1} }{5^3}$

Is this correct?

Comment: I'd say the probability is very high that two of the passengers are a married couple, and they'll most likely be staying at the same hotel. There are a lot of unstated assumptions hiding in the presentation of this problem. Maybe one of the inns is bigger than all the others put together, and that's where most of people on the shuttle go. Maybe the shuttle breaks down on the way, and has to let all the passengers out on the highway (don't laugh – this happened to me once, in San Francisco!).

Answer (score 1):

You forget to multiply the first term in the numerator by $\binom{4}{1}$ i.e. you forgot to assign the lone passenger an inn. Once you do that the answer will be $\frac{13}{25}$.

For this problem listing out the possibilities is still manageable but what if there are $10$ inns and $5$ passengers? An often helpful method is to use complement; calculate the probability that none of them stay in the same inn then the probability we are looking for is $1$ minus that probability.

$$
\begin{align}
p&=1-\frac{5\times 4\times 3}{5^{3}}\\
&=\frac{13}{25}
\end{align}
$$